# CytoscapeJS - show node neighborhood?

Tags: jquery, nodes, cytoscape.js

I have a dataset in JSON format containing information about nodes and edges which I am using to generate a network graph in cytoscapeJS. The JSON data contains id, value, shape, colour and visibleDisplay ('element' or 'none') attributes for **nodes** and id, source, target and label for **edges**. My stylesheet uses this 'visibleDisplay' property to show/ hide nodes, as needed, when the **cy** container is first initialised.

I want to allow users to unhide nodes with an option to **"Show neighbourhood"**. I have modified my old code to make use of collections but it still does not work:

```
function showNeighbourhood() {
   var eleID;
   var neighbourArray= new Array();

   var neighbours= cy.collection(); // collection

   cy.nodes().forEach(function( ele ) {
       if(ele.selected()) { // get the currently selected node.
          eleID= ele.id();
         }
      });

   // Find its connected neighbours.
   cy.edges().forEach(function( edg ) {
       if(edg.data('source') === eleID) {
          neighbourArray[neighbourArray.length]= edg.data('target');
         }
       else if(edg.data('target') === eleID) {
          neighbourArray[neighbourArray.length]= edg.data('source');
         }
      });

   // Add the array to the collection.
   neighbours.add(neighbourArray);

  // Show neighbourhood, using the collection.
   neighbours.show();
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work ?
Can't I use the **show()** method on the collection to make the required nodes visible ?

Comment: cy.on('tap', function(evt){console.log(cy.$('#'+evt.target.id()).neighborhood() ) });
It is showing me an OBJECT..... i just want list of directly attached node... how to get that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need only use `node.neighborhood()`, e.g. `cy.$(':selected').neighborhood().removeClass('hidden')`.

Comment: Thanks Max, I got it to work by using:
`cy.nodes(':selected').neighborhood().nodes().show();`

Comment: cy.on('tap', function(evt){console.log(cy.$('#'+evt.target.id()).neighborhood() ) });
It is showing me an OBJECT..... i just want list of directly attached node... how to get that...