# Show neighbour of selected node

Tags: jquery, angular, cytoscape.js

I m trying to list neighbouring node of selected node using this code..

```
            cy.on('tap', function(evt){
                console.log( cy.$('#'+evt.target.id()).neighborhood());
            });
```

But it is returning some object like this

```
u {0: a, 1: a, 2: a, 3: a, length: 4, _private: Object}.......
```

Now, how to extract nodes and edges from it..
i tried this ([CytoscapeJS - show node neighborhood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970633/cytoscapejs-show-node-neighborhood))... but its not working for me...

Please guide..

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'evt.target' is the element, so no need for the cy.$(.....
Try something like this

```
neighbors = evt.target.neighborhood()
neighbors.forEach(function(ele){
    console.log(ele.id())
})
```

Comment: Thanx brother... but its giving error
evt.neighborhood is not a function at u.<anonymous> (cntrl1.js:78)

Comment: OK.... it is WORKING NOW with

cy.$('#'+evt.target.id()).neighborhood()

Comment: my bad, it should've been evt.target. I've updated my response